# "in a minibus" or "on a minibus"?

Tags: word-choice, prepositions

- We went there **in** a minibus.
- We went there **on** a  minibus.

I know we use "on bus" for travelling by public transportation, but I am not sure it can be used for "minibus" too.

So which is better, "on a minibus" or "in a minibus"?

Comment: Neither. You went there *by* minibus.

Comment: Please explain me more.

Comment: A set phrase, perhaps? I'm not sure how to explain it, but "going by bus" is idiomatic, while *"going on bus" and *"going in bus" aren't.

Comment: "**On** the bus" just refers to where you are.  "**By** bus" refers to *how* you're traveling somewhere.  (Note that you say "by bus" or "by train" because it's general, but you're "on the bus" or "on a bus", not just "on bus.")  So yesterday I was *on* a bus, but I went home *by* bus.  That said, I can imagine saying, "Traveling through Africa on a rusty old bus", but that's slightly different: I was traveling, and I was on a particular bus.

Comment: You need to better define *minibus*. If you mean a form of public transportation, then it is like using *bus*. If it is a personal vehicle, then it is like using *car*.

Comment: @learner You are a teacher of English. Do you teach your students to use the articles in phrases like _in **a** minibus?_

Comment: @P.E.Dant I've edited my question. Thanks for correcting my mistake. I'm only a learner.

Comment: Either one. Depends whether the minibus can be conceived of as having a platform that one can stand *on*  and/or as something that encloses one so that one is *in* it. Trains, planes, buses, even elevators can be conceived of either way.

Answer (score 2):

When you ride things that are public transportation, you can be said to be *on* them.  It's a little weird if multiple people can't use the ride and whatever you are riding is not flat, though.  For example, saying "I'm on a taxi" would sound strange (someone would probably think you are on a giant taxi).  Saying "I'm on a raft" is OK.  You can also say you are on a bus, a boat, a train, a plane, a snowmobile, a horse, etc.

With a truck, you have to be careful.  *On a truck* usually means you are in the cargo section of the truck.  *In a truck* means you are driving or in the passenger seat.

Since most of these things are covered things that you have to enter via a door, it's also appropriate to say that you are *in* them.  Thus, this doesn't work with a boat unless you are in the boat's cabin, and does not work with a raft unless you have a very strange or novel raft.  However you are still *in* a convertible even if the roof is down.

*By* works with any of these, if you didn't drive the vehicle.  "I rode in by bus, boat, train, plane, raft, truck, spaceship, etc."

Minibus is the same as bus.

Answer (score 0):

When you are talking about covered transport, the guide is whether you can stand up and walk around. If you can, then you are 'on' it. *On a plane*, *on a bus*, *on a train* for example. In contrast, if you have to sit down than you are 'in' it. *In a car*, for example.

Uncovered transport, such as bicycles, motorbikes, or horses is a different matter.

Comment: Therefore  for a bus or minibus or other similar things such as trains that can be considered to have a platform you can say *either* on a bus or in a bus. Per your answer, you can both sit down and walk around on a bus, train, plane, and, a minibus, if by minibus we are talking about a half-sized bus or something.